# Since when does MathOverflow become one of SE family?

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow

I am really sorry, it has been a while since I am back on Math.SE, and since when when does MathOverflow become one of SE family? Won't Math.SE and MathOverflow overlap each other?

Comment: MO is for *research* level math, and anything below is off-topic. MSE is for all kinds of math.

Comment: @T.Bongers So what does the MSE community say about this? There must be some heated discussions.

Comment: MO has been part of the SE network since [last June](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/753/history-of-mathoverflow). There's really very little overlap or competition between the sites, and I'm not sure what there'd be heated discussions about.

Comment: @T.Bongers Oh, don't worry about that -- people are apt to find things to have heated discussions about. Like [hypothetical migrations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4880/).

Comment: Related, and possibly duplicate of: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/i-found-mo-has-been-included-in-se-network-today/10068#10068

Comment: There were some heated discussions at MO, not so much at m.se.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since June 25, 2013. See: [MathOverflow 2.0](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1416/6/mathoverflow-20/), [History of MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/753/history-of-mathoverflow). Generally, [meta.MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/) is a better place for questions about MathOverflow.

The sites (oops, they are no longer sites but  *communities*) are quite different  in their focus and thus they complement each other instead of being competitors.  Occasionally, [people ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185784/249296):

> If I have a maths question, on which site should I ask: MathOverflow or Mathematics.SE?

to which there is a [simple answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185784/whats-the-difference-between-mathoverflow-mathematics-se#comment569942_185784):

> If you have to ask, math.SE

Comment: I think this is a great response. I agree - if you have to ask, use MSE.

Comment: (this is the very reason why I stick with MSE, indeed...)